# stackoverflowの画面をキャプチャーした場合の著作権

Tags: サポート

英語版含めて検索しても見当たらなかったため質問です

youtube投稿用に作業の映像をキャプチャしていたところ
スタックオーバーフローの画面もキャプチャされました
youtubeに投稿しても著作権違反にならないでしょうか？

余談ですがソースコードに関するライセンスの規約は発見できました
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321291/the-licenses-of-code-on-stack-overflow

Comment: キャプチャに映りこんだ内容についての説明もあるとよいかもしれません。(単なるロゴとかなのか、または誰かが投稿した質問や回答なのか等)

Answer (score 6):

まず、法律に関する厳密な判断を一般のユーザーがすることは難しいということをご理解くださいませ。

その上で、スタック・オーバーフロー上のコンテンツには 2020 年 2 月現在次のライセンスがかかっています。サイト下部に書かれています。

> site design / logo © 2020 Stack Exchange Inc; user contributions licensed under cc by-sa 4.0 with attribution required.

つまり、サイトのデザイン等は SE 社が著作権を持っています。また、ソースコードに限らずユーザーが投稿したものに関しては[クリエイティブ・コモンズ 表示 - 継承 4.0 国際](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/deed.ja) (CC BY-SA 4.0) でライセンスされています。